# kendoui react DateRangePicker - move the labels on the left

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

the default DateRangePicker has the labels on top, is it possible to move on the left of the input box?

```
Label
 ------------                   ---------
|            |   --->    Label |         |
 ------------                   ---------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can custom label by overide css

**global.css**

```
.k-floating-label-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.k-label {
    position: static !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    display: block;
    order: -1;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You can see in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-herschel-nu3xhb?file=/public/index.html:3938-4279)